# How to create framework with inner frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I  absolutely can not understand how it works. I started with a simple one: created framework using "Cocoa Touch Framework" template and add some code to source files. Then using cocoapods I installed some pods to this framework-project. All looks good (maybe not so good actually) and build fine. After that there was an attempt to connect my framework to other xcode project. I did this as follows: just took my test.framework file from Product folder and transferred to another project. At first everything was not bad. The import was successful and I can use my framework-code in another project. But when I run it I have error: **dyld: Library not loaded: Reason: image not found.** I tried all of the answers to this problem, but nothing helped me.

After that, it was decided to try to connect my framework to other project. This time I got a completely different behavior: namely, I was able to connect the framework, but I could not access the code inside it. I'm completely confused, because I did not change anything. I just did the same with another project.

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

A related questions:

- Can I connect the framework just moving test.framework file into
  another project?
- For some reason, I should use the approach described above, is there a chance in the theory of success or all that I have done before is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it a lot with the same result you get , until I posted the problem in Apple forums and they respond with Nested frameworks are not supported in IOS
[image]

Comment: Clear. Maybe there are some assumptions why the same code behaves differently when connected to different projects?